# Finding drive time between two points based on matching value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, origin-destination

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I'm trying to find drive times between two points with Network Analyst. I'm trying to find the time between the origin and the destination based on a value in the origin. So if the origin is supposed to connect to destination 'A' I want to find that drive time regardless if it's the closest or not.

Is there a way I can specify this in the OD Cost Matrix tool or another tool?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a notebook and write a loop to capture the unique values shared by origin and destination points. You should derive a list, then use that list to iterate over each value and use the value in the definition query for origin and destination points before running Add Locations on each. Within the same loop, run Solve. And last, (presumably you're interested in the outputted line features), append all of these lines into a master feature class. Don't forget to remove the origin and destination points from the previous iteration.

This way you run your analysis once per matching origin and destination values (the ones that are 'supposed' to match) yet end up with a feature class that accounts for all origins and destinations.

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks!